# Using ExceltoWord! and getting "1004, Unable to get the text property of the worksheetfunction class"

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to create an ExceltoWord! template to transfer typing automatically into a word document from Excel. 
At the moment I insert a narrative I want to use into the cell, and it is giving me a 1004 error. It appears to be based on the amount of text I put into the cell, because, when I shorten the passage, it will allow me to post the information. Is there a way to allow longer text passages to be updated into the word document?
The debugger code giving me the error is:

```
If myObjCopy.Value <> "" Then
    BkMk.Range.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(myObjCopy.Value, myObjCopy.NumberFormat)
Else
    BkMk.Range.Text = myObjCopy.Value 'use base format for all else
End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```

Comment: Don't use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Text`. Use `Format$()`.

Comment: So that helps get the written information into the word document, however, I had another page with numbers on it, and those do not transfer now. It was a multipage (tab) excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error,in an older iteration the error produced the `255 character limit error` however came back this time as the `1004`.

From the original Excelto Word thread an answer was provided, please see below.

All you have to do is comment out the following by adding a `'` before two lines:

```
If myObjCopy.Value <> "" Then
                            'BkMk.Range.Text =     Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(myObjCopy.Value, myObjCopy.NumberFormat)
                        'Else
                            BkMk.Range.Text = myObjCopy.Value 'use base format for all else
                        End If
```